# What information has been released regarding the .NET Framework 4.0?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

As Microsoft seems to have started their trickle feed of information regarding .NET 4.0, I thought I'd ask the question as I'm sure there's more out there than I've spotted!

What information has been released regarding the .NET Framework 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InfoQ has some good information, but doesn't go into the details.

- [Type embedding](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/10/Type-Embedding)
- [Dynamic types in C#](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/10/CSharp-Dynamic)
- [Optional parameters in C#](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/10/CSharp-Optional)
- [Type covariance and contravariance](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/10/CSharp-Variance)

Microsoft have an information page for downloading the Visual Studio 2010 and .Net 4 CTP [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/content/content.aspx?ContentID=9790).

Answer (score 0):

http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&ned=us&q=net+Framework+4.0&btnG=Search+News is a good place to start

Comment: Vote it down all you want.. in 6 months, this will still be a valid link where the others will be dated

Comment: Firstly, it wasn't me voting down :=) (Just thought I'd say that before the rest of my comment!).. Yes, the google link will still be valid, but it's changeable. What I see today from that link could be different from what someone else sees tomorrow. Is that really "in the spirit" of answers here?

Comment: No worries. :) I guess I look at the question as part of a knowledge base for the future. The answer of the question is dynamic when you account for time, so what you see SHOULD be different if newer information is available.  It's very similar to linking to a Wikipedia entry.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly marketing "spiel", but there's [a post](http://blogs.msdn.com/stevemar/archive/2008/10/01/the-road-to-pdc-net-framework-4-0-and-dublin.aspx) on Steven Martin's blog discussing some of the new things to come in WF/WCF.

Answer (score 0):

[ComputerWorld Australia](http://www.computerworld.com.au/index.php/id;1149786074;pp;1) just ran an [excellent interview](http://www.computerworld.com.au/index.php/id;1149786074;pp;1) with Anders Hejlsberg , in which he talks a little bit about what's coming in C# 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

[This video on Channel9 provided some interesting information on the next version of C#.](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Charles/C-40-Meet-the-Design-Team/)  Obviously, some of these changes will have to be backed into the CLR...

(Video is of Anders etal talking about 4.0 in the room C# was born)